# VS Cordova IOS Remote Build

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am new to cordova and trying to get my env all set up. I was able to successfully get an ios cordova app running on my mac. I then installed the remote build agent for vs and tried to create a new ios project in vs. In ripple it works fine but when I try to do a remote build I get the following error

> Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error
>   Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-ios version.
>   cordova-ios: 3.8.0, failed version requirement: >=4.0.0-dev:
>   {1}   BlankCordovaApp1

Where do I set the cordova-ios version for the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is coming from the `cordova-plugin-whitelist` plugin included with new Visual Studio Typescript projects by default. The values are inside `plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/plugin.xml`.

In theory you could change the cordova-ios version number in this file, but I couldn't get that to work, so I just removed the whitelist plugin altogether.

Remove the plugin by deleting it from the /plugins folder and removing the following from the project's `config.xml`:

`<!-- Support for Cordova 5.0.0 plugin system -->
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />`

Answer (score 1):

The latest version 1.1.0 requires cordova-ios 4.0.0 as the error message suggests. Version 1.0.0 does support 3.8.0 so an easy fix is to use that version instead. To use 1.0.0 you can add the following to the

config.xml

```
<vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1.0.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to update your Visual Studio 2015 Cordova Tool.  From Visual Studio 2015 click on Tools-> Extensions and Updates.  If you need the update, you would see a Apache Cordova Update listed.  If so complete the install and that should solves your issue.

Cheers